# Prove combinatorially: $\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r}CC^{k-r}_n = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

> $n > k > 0$. $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> Prove combinatorially (without algebric manipulation): $\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r}CC^{k-r}_n = 0$

*Note: $CC^{k}_n$ is the number of options to choose $k$ objects out of $n$ different types with repetitions and without order. For example it is the same as the number of options to put $k$ balls in $n$ cells (no order for cells, with repetitions of balls in each cell).
It is equal to $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$*

I have no clue sadly, looking for a hint on how to approach this.

Comment: I wrote $k > n$ by mistake, fixed now

Comment: $\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} \dots$ strongly suggests inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @RobPratt If I think about it like that I find that $P_i = $ "There is a ball in the $i$-th cell". so $E(0)$ which is equal to the sum would be "All cells are empty" which should be equal to $1$ shouldn't it? instead of $0$.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you, I solved it in a slightly different matter (thinking about balls and cells)